# Is singleton method call bypassing possible in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was learning the object individuation in my `IRB` and I did try the code below:

```
class Foo
    def talk
        p "huanng"
    end
end
#=> nil

module Bar
    def talk
        p "hunnggg"
    end
end
#=> nil

foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x1152b88>

class << foo
    def talk
        p "hukkangg"
    end
 include Bar
end
#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x1152b88>>

foo.talk
"hukkangg"
#=> "hukkangg"
```

The above output is so obvious.

Anyway to by pass the call the singleton method `talk` on the object `foo` and to execute the method `talk` inside the `class Foo` using `foo.talk` ?

Looking for the output on the call `foo.talk` as `"huanng"`.

***EDIT:***

As per the suggestions from **@Anthony Alberto** I can reach to `talk` of `Bar`.

```
class Foo
    def talk
        p "huanng"
    end
end
#=> nil

module Bar
    def talk
        p "hunnggg"
    end
end
#=> nil

foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x1152b88>

class << foo
    def talk
        super
        return
        p "hukkangg"
    end
    include Bar
end
#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x11f6670>>

foo.talk
"hunnggg"
#=> nil
```

On the same route how to reach `talk` of `Foo` bypassing the singleton method `talk` and `talk` of `Bar`?

***EDIT***

Finally not the answer but close to the actual need is as per **@Neil**

```
class Foo
    def talk
        p "huanng"
    end
end
#=> nil

module Bar
    def talk
        p "hunnggg"
    end
end
#=> nil

foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x1152b88>

class << foo
    def talk
     p "hukkangg"
    end
   include Bar
end

#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x1200db0>>

foo.dup.talk
#"huanng"
#=> "huanng"

foo.talk
#"hukkangg"
#=> "hukkangg"
```

Comment: Not sure of the question. Are you wanting to call Foo's instance method "talk" by finding it and calling it, or looking for a way to undo the change to the instance (but just for your chosen method)?

Comment: Looking for the output on the call `foo.talk` as `"huanng"` when a same name method `talk` also defined on `foo` as singleton method.

Comment: How are you then expecting to call the singleton method?

Comment: I was just checking if possible or not.If anyone aware of such techniques or not.

Comment: except reopening the singleton class and overriding the `talk` method to call `super` or something similar, you can't as far as I know ...

Comment: If you simply re-do the instance class def and call "super", you end up calling Bar's "talk", at least that's what I get in irb.

Comment: It's a well asked question that will help learn a bit of Ruby, so +1 from me. Although, if you ever _needed_ this to solve a problem I'd say there was a big problem with your design! :)

Comment: @Neil Oh yeah, I misread the desired output, they were quite confusing though :p

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto method bypassing also I did with `return` and your one `super`. means we can by pass on the same object `foo`. Just keeping my finger cross to anyway to reach to `talk` of `Foo`. Which is still open :) `foo.dup` seems that we reached to the destination but it is not on the same object as `foo`. It's on `foo.dup` in reality. :)

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto Hey Guys answer has been posted,you can take a look into the same. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, although it is (understandably) convoluted. You take the instance method from the class (which bypasses the singleton class) and call it on `foo`:

```
an_unbound_method = foo.class.instance_method(:talk)
a_bound_method = an_unbound_method.bind(foo)
a_bound_method.call
```

Comment: probably that's the one I was looking for. Awsome :) ... what is `bind` doing? I never used `bind` till now in my 1.5 months of Ruby age. `+1` to you. Could you also explain how does `bind` help in bypassing?

Comment: Could you tell me how your answer able to bypass? how the method look-up happened with your style, for which singleton method `talk` has been skipped?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't technically call against the same instance, but dup won't copy the singleton stuff (clone *will*), so you can do this:

```
foo.dup.talk
```

. . . and it might be good enough in some situations?

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this one.